# How to redirect user to authentication page when he tries to enter the url of the secured page ?

Tags: spring-security

I'm using spring security to authenticate users, if it's the right user :he has access to the home page ..
But when I tried  to enter with the url (without entering my name or my password ) an anonymous user can see the home page !

My application is not secured !

Could someone help me please ?

This is my **spring-securityConfig.xml** :

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" default-target-url="/accueil"
        authentication-failure-url="/403" always-use-default-target="true"   />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" /> 
    <http-basic/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**"  />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="userService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: i dont know if this may be what you want but you could assign the obtained values (user and pass) from your login form to make a simple "if" on every page loader to check if the user variable is not the default and if his password matches also add a regex to your login form so they cant mess up your code

Comment: Thanks for your response @ivan.. you meant I should use a simple "if" in my jsp page ? a php code ?

Comment: yeah, just make 1 or 2 global variables with default values and then  assign the returned values of your form to the global variables and just add and "if" to check if the variable still has the default value

Comment: Could you please post an example or  a link , I'm new with php 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how to create a variable in jsp:
http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/global-variable-in-jsp/
spring security get username to variable:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/

and im assuming that you know how to redirect and make an if, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try it ..

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this with `auto-config="true"`, but you should have something like this instead: `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />`. I believe you have to set the `http` flag `use-expressions="true"`. Check this link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html

Comment: Thanks for your response @Thiago , I tried to add it, when I entered the url of the home page I have no more access to it , But I had a loop of redirections to a login page That is not shown ! Are there any other configurations to redirect the user to authenticate first (to my custom login page ) ? 
     
and I've tried to login with a valid username and password , it generated an exception (nullPointerException) !? What should I do here  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything for the redirection, it comes with Spring Security by default. It's just that your home page isn't secure. Did you try

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />    
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sanjay, I tried to add `<intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" /> ` , when I  entered  the url of the home page I have  no more  access to it , But I had a loop of  redirections  to a login page That  is not shown !

Are there any other configurations  to redirect the user to authenticate first (to  my custom login page ) ?

Comment: and I've tried to login with a valid username and password , it generated an exception (nullPointerException) !? What should I do ?

Comment: I think the login url itself might have got restricted, thus causing the redirection. You can try opening the login page to all, and restricting the other url.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand your suggestion.. you mean there are 2 login pages ?

Comment: I meant trying to add an intercept-url for /login*, permitting it to all. Have updated my answer - see above.